# clang-format: Empty line between end of class declaration and closing of a namespace

Tags: c++, clang, code-formatting, clang-format

I use clang-format to format our C++ code. I would like to have an empty line between the class declaration and the closing brace of the surrounding namespace like so:

```
namespace Foo {

class Bar {
};

}
```

But clang-format changes my code to this:

```
namespace Foo {

class Bar {
};
}
```

It removes the empty line between the class declaration and the closing brace of the namespace.

My question: Is there a way to prevent clang-format removing the empty line?

This is my current clang-format configuration:

```
Language: Cpp
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: true
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: false
AlignOperands: false
AlignTrailingComments: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
ColumnLimit: 80
CommentPragmas: '^ IWYU pragma:'
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 0
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: true
DisableFormat: false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
ForEachMacros: [foreach, Q_FOREACH, BOOST_FOREACH]
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentWidth: 4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd: ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 1
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 200
PointerAlignment: Left
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 4
SpacesInAngles: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard: Cpp11
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found one way to workaround this: add an inline comment to your namespace closing brace, as follows:

```
namespace my_namespace {

class MyClass {
    int n;
};

} // namespace my_namespace
```

Comment: FixNamespaceComments: true (clang 11) may do this for you automagically too.