# clang format: break before braces, empty line after opening brace and empty line before closing brace

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm trying to format classes inside namespaces in the following way (`BreakBeforeBraces: Allman`):

```
namespace test_a::test_b
{

struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

}  // namespace test_a::test_b
```

but clang format keeps changing it to

```
namespace test_a::test_b
{
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

}  // namespace test_a::test_b
```

The workaround [in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547172/clang-format-empty-line-between-end-of-class-declaration-and-closing-of-a-names) question works only with configurations like `BasedOnStyle: Google` no brakes **before** opening braces for example

```
namespace test_a::test_b {

struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
};

}  // namespace test_a::test_b
```

Same for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477654/how-to-make-clang-format-add-new-line-before-opening-brace-of-a-function)

I want clang-format to always add an empty line after namespace opening brace and before closing brace, is that possible?

**For clarity, this is the clang-format I use**

```
---
BasedOnStyle: Google
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: 'true'
BinPackArguments: 'false'
BinPackParameters: 'false'
IndentWidth: '4'
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: 'true'
ColumnLimit: 120
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clang format can't do that specifically for namespace for the moment, but you can use `KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks` to put empty line for all blocks. what if you use `BreakBeforeBraces: Custom` ?

Comment: I tried "BreakBeforeBraces: Custom". it's only giving you the freedom to choose where to break, but it keeps removing spaces. So this is not the answer, but "KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks" is working splendidly, so thank you!